# What is NOR logical operator?

Tags: language-agnostic, logic, boolean

Is *nor*:

!(a or b)
!a or !b
!(a and b)

something else?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

!(a or b)

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR for more:

> In [boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic), **logical nor** or **joint denial** is a truth-functional operator which produces a result that is the negation of [logical or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction). That is, a sentence of the form (*p* NOR *q*) is true precisely when neither p nor q is true—i.e. when both of *p* and *q* are false. In [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar), **nor** is a [coordinating conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_conjunction)...

Answer (score 11):

[!(a or b)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_NOR)

Answer (score 10):

`NOR(a, b)` is defined to be `NOT(OR(a, b))` which is `!(a or b)` in infix notation.  By [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Laws), this is also equivalent to `(!a) and (!b)`.

Answer (score 6):

`((a NAND a) NAND (b NAND b)) NAND ((a NAND a) NAND (b NAND b))` if you want to be circuit fabrication friendly. :)

Answer (score 5):

your first alternative: `!`(a or b)

which happens to be equivalent to !a and !b