# Understanding And/Or logic VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I'm so confused about why the second `If` statement works but the first one does not.

The actual result I want is if the user does not enter Peach or Banana or Mango then show the message.

The `Or`'s in the sentence above makes the most sense. However, if I said "if the user does not enter Peach and Banana and Mango" then show the message - It sounds like you would need to enter all three fruits to show the message which is not the result I'm looking for. But! It's the one that works.

The second `If` statement shows the message if none of the correct fruit is entered however, the first statement does not work at all.

Please help clarify.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Apple |
| Cell 2 | Orange |

```vb
If Item.Value <> "Peach" or Item.Value <> "Banana" or Item.Value <> "Mango" Then
   MsgBox "Fruit Not Available"
End If
```

```vb
If Item.Value <> "Peach" And Item.Value <> "Banana" And Item.Value <> "Mango" Then
   MsgBox "Fruit Not Available"
End If
```

I tried both statements but only the second one works and I'm confused why that is.

Comment: You have `If x <> 1 Or x <> 2`. X is equal to 2. What will the `If` evaluate to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/913963. `!(a or b)` = `(!a) and (!b)`. This is just logic.

Comment: @GSerg Anything other than 1 or 2

Comment: @BigBen The link you provided says !(a or b) = Not a nor b which is what I want but the OR doesnt give me this the AND statement does

Comment: Correct. What that link says is that `!(a or b)` is equvalent to `(!a) and (!b)`. It is not equivalent to `(!a) or (!b)`, which is your first (incorrect) attempt. Your second attempt, where you use `and`, is correct. Note the placement of parentheses too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA will evaluate each of the comparisons to true/false

Lets assume the Item.Value = "Peach"

so we get:

```
false = Item.Value <> "Peach"
true = Item.Value <> "Banana"
true = Item.Value <> "Mango"
```

Having this in the first or will give you:

```
true = false or true or true
```

Regardsless if the value is any of the fruits or not, it will give you always true and will not work.

Having this in the second AND will give you:

```
false = false AND true AND true
```

This is when one fruit is a match. If Item.Value = "Apple" you will get:

```
true = true  AND true AND true
```

for you this results in "the second statement works" where as they both work correctly but the first has no value for you.